# Linear Algebra - A question about eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have received the following question, and I find it difficult to prove.

> We are in the real numbers "world".
> Given two matrices, A,B, both have n rows and n coloumns of real numbers, let v be an eigenvector of both A and B.
> Prove that v is an eigenvector of 3A-4B.

I'm scanning my whole notebook but I can't find any relevant sentence that can assist me here.
The only thing I know about A and B is that they hold real numbers.
They have one common eigenvector.
I can't connect any of them to be an unitary or hermit matrix. Therefore, I find it difficult to prove the quote.
Can anyone please assist me by giving me a hint to the solution?
The question is from an older test of our college, perhaps we haven't learnt the idea of how to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what makes an eigenvector an eigenvector?

Comment: As said by Sean: come back to the definition $AV=\lambda V, BV=\lambda V$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the eigenvector for $A$ and $B$, perhaps associated to different eigenvalues.
$$A v = \lambda v, \quad B v = \mu v$$
Then
$$(3A-4B)\ v = 3 \lambda v -4 \mu v = (3\lambda-4\mu) \ v$$
and you are done.